# Update/delete aws_s3_object results in "InvalidArgument: Invalid attribute name specified."

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-iot

I have a project where I create AWS IoT certificates using Terraform and store them in an Amazon S3 bucket.

I store the certificates using `aws_s3_object` and the content attribute:

```
resource "aws_iot_certificate" "this" {
  count = length(aws_iot_thing.this)

  active = true
}

resource "aws_s3_object" "public_key" {
  count = length(var.things)

  bucket  = module.s3_bucket.s3_bucket_id
  key     = "certificate/${var.things[count.index].customer_id}/public_key.pem"
  content = aws_iot_certificate.this[count.index].public_key
}
```

The application works, but when I try to create or destroy the objects, Terraform always gives me this error:

```
Error: deleting S3 Bucket (xxxxxxx) Object (certificate/xxxx/public_key.pem): InvalidArgument: Invalid attribute name specified. status code: 400, request id: xxxxx, host id: xxxx
```

I tried to use a constant key like "test/public_key.pem", with the same result.

Comment: See [terraform-provider-aws/issues/32307](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/32307).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like jarmod mentioned the problem was mentioned in the Terraform AWS provider [issue 32307](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/32307) and fixed in the provider version 5.6.2.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).